# Heroku on Windows: unable to "run" anything

Tags: heroku

When I try to run "heroku run rake db:migrate" or any other "heroku run <...>" command, I get this:

> C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.2.4/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:213:in
>   `` `': No such file or directory - tput
>   cols (Errno::ENOENT)
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.2.4/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:213:in ``
>   get_terminal_environment'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.2.4/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:16:in `index'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.2.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:114:in`
>   run'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.2.4/bin/heroku:14:in `<top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby192/bin/heroku:19:in`load'
>           from C:/Ruby192/bin/heroku:19:in `'

How do I fix this?

Windows 7, 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by installing cygwin ncurses package.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you looking for `rake` rather than `run`?

Try `heroku rake db:migrate`

Comment: heroku run is the new method for running rake/console commands on the new Cedar stack so it is correct if he's running on Cedar.